# GeoServer doesn't render SVG markers properly

Tags: geoserver, style, sld, svg, css

GeoServer Version 2.21.0
GeoTools Version 27.0
GeoWebCache Version 1.21.0

GeoServer doesn't render SVG external graphic well, the graphics is cut and not all visible- only about upper left square is visible.
It's look like a bug, don't know. Does anybody have the same problem? It look weird.
Tried with both SLD and CSS
Here is the SVG marker: https://geocash.xyz/resources/bin2.svg

Here is the CSS style:

```
* {
    mark: url(https://geocash.xyz/resources/bin2.svg);
    mark-mime: "image/svg+xml";
    mark-size: 44;
 }
```

Here is the layer preview:
[image]

Comment: Does the same issue exist for a pure GetMap image outside of the OpenLayers preview

Comment: Yes, it’s still exist.

Comment: The mark-size is 44 while the viewbox is 34?

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to [Olav](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/211856/olav)! You were right, man!
The SVG is created in Inkscape, I had to be careful with Document properties:

the view box needed to be verified AND SET in same units, as the page size:

[image: screenshot]

My fault was, that I have saved the SVG with the same size for the page, but they were in *pt*. But in the SVG source code, checked in VSCode, there are just numbers, units are not presented. So, the renderer was just rendering the smaller viewbox of the bigger paths inside.